# different methods on one standard headCell in func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 tableviews in the same view controller: "studentsTable" and "professorsTable". I wanted to create a standard head cell for both tables. I subclassed the UItableViewCell and created headCell type. Then assigned one headCell to both if indexPath.row==0.   Everything went smooth, however, there is 1 problem. Whenever I click the "addingButton" I want  "addStudent" function to be called if it was on "studentsTable" and "addProfessor" if it was on "ProfessorsTable". Obviously I can just create two headCells, one for each of the tables but I wonder if there is a more professional way of handling this with writing less code.
 Here is the code I suppose may work if the right "if" condition is given.
Thanks in advance

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

  var actionType:String=String()

  if(/*WHAT CONDITION SHOULD I PUT?*/)
    {actionType="addStudent"}
   else
   {actionType="addProfessor"}


    if(indexPath.row==0)
           {  
             var theHeadcell : headCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headCell") as headCell

           // cell setup

             if(actionType != "")
                {
                   addButton.addTarget(self, action: NSSelectorFromString(actionType), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                }
              return theHeadCell
           }

    else
     { 
        if (tableView==self.studentsTable)
             {
                 var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentsCell") as UITableViewCell

                  // cell setup
                  return cell
             }

       else 
           {
                    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfessorsCell") as UITableViewCell

                // cell setup
                return Cell
           }

   }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if tableView == self.studentsTable
    {actionType = "addStudent"}
else if tableView == self.professorsTable
   {actionType = "addProfessor"}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I messed up something in the code that's why your answer was not working before. I fixed it now. Thank you

Comment: @TikoHarutyunyan I think you may try to judge from UIbutton action method, via `sender.superview.superview` (which should be the tableView)